# Exporting New record set from Access table to the specified Excel Sheet

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access-2013

I am new to VBA.So please bear with me. !!
I have a access database on Shared drive and in that if table gets new record it will automatically export the records to the specified excel sheet. And if someone can provide me the code for it, will be a great help and explain a little.

Answer (score 0):

Access tables themselves don't have a trigger mechanism (at least not up to my ancient version of 2003, though I think the newer versions have one). Typically with Access though you're going to have a data-entry frontend anyway, and you can put the trigger code there on the insert. Here's an example:

I have a table of friends:

[image]

and here's the data-entry frontend for it:

[image]

when I add a new friend name, this code runs:

```
'Get the data of the newest record
Set rec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from Friends where ID=(select max(ID) from Friends)")

'open Excel
Set excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open("c:\_a\mySheet.xlsx")

'find the last cell without data
emptyCell = False
rowNum = 1
Do While emptyCell = False
    If workbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowNum, 1) = "" Then
        Exit Do
    Else
        rowNum = rowNum + 1
    End If
Loop

workbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowNum, 1).Value = rec.Fields("FriendName")

'save and close the Excel sheet
workbook.Save
workbook.Close

'close the recordset
rec.Close

'quit excel
excel.Quit
```

Now when I look in the Excel spreadsheet, it's added the record at the bottom of the cells:

[image]